# How to change the order of words with alphabetic order

Tags: r, alphabetical

I got a dataset with a list of keywords (1 keyword / row).

1. I m looking for a way to create a new column (ALPHABETICAL) based on the KEYWORD column. The value of the ALPHABETICAL column should be auto generated based on the keyword, but words should be ordered alphabetically.

Like this :

```
 | KEYWORD            | ALPHABETICAL       |
 | house blue         | blue house         | 
 | blue house         | blue house         | 
 | my blue house      | blue house my      | 
 | this house is blue | blue house is this | 
 | sky orange         | orange sky         | 
 | orange sky         | orange sky         | 
 | the orange sky     | orange sky the     |
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any attempts you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with dplyr + stringr

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
KEYWORDS  <- c('house blue','blue house','my blue house','this house is blue','sky orange','orange sky','the orange sky')

ALPHABETICAL <- KEYWORDS %>% str_split(., ' ') %>% lapply(., 'sort') %>%  lapply(., 'paste', collapse=' ') %>% unlist(.)
```

The last line uses str_split() to split the KEYWORDS into a list of vectors; sort is then applied to each list element; the vectors are concatenated using paste, and finally the list is broken into a vector.

The result is

```
> cbind(KEYWORDS, ALPHABETICAL)
     KEYWORDS             ALPHABETICAL        
[1,] "house blue"         "blue house"        
[2,] "blue house"         "blue house"        
[3,] "my blue house"      "blue house my"     
[4,] "this house is blue" "blue house is this"
[5,] "sky orange"         "orange sky"        
[6,] "orange sky"         "orange sky"        
[7,] "the orange sky"     "orange sky the"
```

Answer (score 6):

Iterate over rows to split by `" "`(`strsplit`), sort and collapse back:

```
# Generate data
df <- data.frame(KEYWORD = c(paste(sample(letters, 3), collapse = " "), 
                             paste(sample(letters, 3), collapse = " ")))
#  KEYWORD
#   z e s
#   d a u

df$ALPHABETICAL  <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))),
                                                   collapse = " "))
#  KEYWORD ALPHABETICAL
#   z e s        e s z
#   d a u        a d u
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I target the specific column KEYWORDS to create ALPHABETICAL ? (my real dataset contains several other columns)

Comment: @Remi to target specific column use `sapply(df$KEYWORD, ...` instead of `apply(df, 1, ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
df$ALPHABETICAL <- sapply(strsplit(df$KEYWORD," "),function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse=" "))

df
#              KEYWORD       ALPHABETICAL
# 1         house blue         blue house
# 2         blue house         blue house
# 3      my blue house      blue house my
# 4 this house is blue blue house is this
# 5         sky orange         orange sky
# 6         orange sky         orange sky
# 7     the orange sky     orange sky the
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(KEYWORD = c(
  'house blue',
  'blue house',
  'my blue house',
  'this house is blue',
  'sky orange',
  'orange sky',
  'the orange sky'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```