# Sort each string alphabetically in column

Tags: r, string

How can I sort each individual string in a column alphabetically? For example, below is what an optimal output would look like:

```
> x
      Current Age        Want
1 FrankGeorge  25 aeefggknorr
2    BobHenry  29    bbehnory
3 MichaelJohn  30 acehhijlmno
```

I just want each individual cell sorted alphabetically. I've already seen the responses in both [R: Sort a string of items alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337732/r-sort-a-string-of-items-alphabetically) and [How to change the order of words with alphabetic order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304462/how-to-change-the-order-of-words-with-alphabetic-order) and unfortunately they aren't achieving my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the 'Current' column with `strsplit`, loop over the `list` with `sapply`, and `paste` the `sort`ed characters

```
sapply(strsplit(tolower(x$Current), ""), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))
#[1] "aeefggknorr" "bbehnory"    "acehhijlmno"
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(Current = c("FrankGeorge", "BobHenry", "MichaelJohn"
), Age = c(25L, 29L, 30L), Want = c("aeefggknorr", "bbehnory", 
"acehhijlmno")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3"))
```